# In the method "from_dash" when we return "cls(*string.split("-"))" , what exactly is being assigned to the object "karan"? Please someone explain me

Tags: python, class, oop, class-method

```
class Employee:

        def __init__(self, aname, asalary, arole):
        self.name = aname
        self.salary = asalary
        self.role = arole

    def printdetails(self):
        return f"The Name is {self.name}. Salary is {self.salary} and role is {self.role}"

    @classmethod
    def change_leaves(cls, newleaves):
        cls.no_of_leaves = newleaves

    @classmethod
    def from_dash(cls, string):
        # params = string.split("-")
        # print(params)
        # return cls(params[0], params[1], params[2])
        return cls(*string.split("-"))  #what is happening from this point exactly?


harry = Employee("Harry", 255, "Instructor")
rohan = Employee("Rohan", 455, "Student")
karan = Employee.from_dash("Karan-480-Student")

print(karan.printDetails())
```

> Here as per code, object "karan= Employee.from_dash("Karan-480-Student")", But i want to understand what exactly is happening from the point we return cls(*string.split("-")) from class method "from_dash"? Like for karan object are we passing the returned tuple to the **init** constructor of Employee class and assigning "karan" to name, "480" to salary and "Student" to role? or something else is going on ?

Comment: Break it down. What does `string.split("-")` do? What does the `*` do? What does `Employee.__init__` method expect?

Answer (score 0):

```
return cls(*string.split("-"))
```

will evaluate to

```py
return cls(*["Karan", "480", "Student"])
```

The `cls`'s `__init__` will be called, in our case, the `cls` is Employee, who's `__init__` needs `aname, asalary, arole`.

In our expanded statement, we have a list of 3 values, which will be unpacked (thanks to the `*` operator) and mapped to the corresponding element in the `__init__` method.

Comment: Okay..now im getting it a little bit. So  this statement 
karan = Employee.from_dash("Karan-480-Student") is equivalent to 
karan= Employee(*["Karan", "480", "Student"])?? is my understanding right?

Comment: yes, you are right